# Sphinx toctree contains reference to nonexisting document

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I am very new to Sphinx.  Doc says it is easy to set up - maybe so but I am having a bear of a time.  I finally have .rst files being created but while I have updated index.rst I am getting this error.  I confirmed the .rst files exist in the /docs directory.  Below are the syspath from my conf.py and the index.

I have tried all of these combinations without success - the .rst files reside in /home/efultz/src/Sicom2.0/docs

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/efultz/src/Sicom2.0/'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/efultz/src/Sicom2.0/docs'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/efultz/src/Sicom2.0/')
```

I have the following in the index.rst - I have confirmed there are only 3 spaces before the individual filenames

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   Base
   BaseAPI
   EventLogger
   SICOMToConnex
   SICOMToConnexAPI
   SICOMToConnexAPIProduct
   SICOMToConnexDemo
   SICOMToConnexParser
   SICOMToConnexParserAPI
   SICOMToConnexParserAPIProduct
   product
   modules
```

Comment: Are the documents listed in the `toctree` located in the same directory as index.rst?

Comment: No - under docs I have build and source - the .rst files are under docs while the  index.rst is in the source directory.  I moved the files to the source directory and things are working now - is there a path that will work without my moving the files?

Comment: I think you should put all RST files in the **docs** directory.

Comment: Modifying `sys.path` has no effect on the way a toctree works.

Answer (score 3):

I found by configuring to use the same directory instead of splitting directories when the .RST files were created they were where they needed to be.